# Is there a way to pause eval() after each executed statement?

Tags: javascript, virtual-machine, eval

Is there a way to pause pause the eval() function in javascript after each statement that was executed within eval()?

Or is there something like like a virtual machine in javascript, that I can initialize from my code, give it some code to run but also can be completely paused without interfering with my code outside of the vm?

**Background:**
I'm building a game in javascript where people can write their own javascript code, then press a play button and then the code is executed to control a character in the game. For reasons the code execution for the user-code needs to be synchonous with the view of the gameworld, so everytime a statement like move() is called, the character should first move in the gameworld, then I want the execution of the user code to be paused for some time and after that the next line of code by the user is being executed.

**What I've tried:**
I tried approaches like slicing the user code and inserting functions to pause after each line of code and wrapping it all in an asynch function afterwards, but tinkering with the user input is a path of suffering it seems, especially when the user writes their own functions and they are not asynch it breaks down.

So if you have completely different approaches for that problem, they are welcome as well.

Comment: yes, a different approach would be to program your own interpreter for a subset of javascript or any other language of choice. Sound complicated, but it will pay out in the long run.

Comment: Thank you! As someone not very experienced with low level programming that is a very helpful startingpoint.